# Recreating Process Flow in Python NetworkX

Tags: python, networkx, dataflow-diagram

Would anyone know how to recreate this flow chart in `networkx`? I know I can manually add these nodes and add the edges, but I wanted to write some code that could be applicable for other data types like `CSV` or `EXCEl`.

My main idea was to convert this flow into Excel and then have the program read that file and create nodes and edge.

I do have something that is able to read the file and then create nodes using that file. However, I cannot get the edges and the specificities of the flow correct in network.

If anyone could help that would be great. Thanks

[image]

> This is the flow I wish to recreate

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I would try loading the csv into a pandas dataframe. Networkx can be very finicky on how the incoming data needs to be formatted.  So I would import it to the dataframe the have networkx read it out of there.